# Codeigniter -- working with multiple controllers

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, routes, uri

I have a question which regards to controllers. Let's get it started:

- I have a main controller named "admin.php", it has a menu for company, user management, etc. Each item on the menu has separate PHP file to hold different kinds data [I seems to be lengthy to combine them all in one php.

So for this example:

I have 3 controllers: admin.php , company.php, usermanagement.php

What I want is, link the company and management controllers as a child of admin. So if enter the address on the browser, it may look: localhost/admin/company and localhost/admin/usermanagement

I configured the routes and it's good but when I enter "localhost/company" it loads the company page which i didn't want to. i wanted to link them all as a child of an admin page.

How would I achieve this?

by the way here's a snippet of my code:

**admin.php** - Controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Admin extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        session_start();
    }

    public function index() {
          $this->load->view('view_admin');
       }
}
```

**Company** - Same as the admin

```
  <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Company extends CI_Controller {

        function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();

            session_start();
        }

        public function index() {
              $this->load->view('view_company');
           }
    }
```

Thanks,
James

**EDIT:** I have tried adding functions on the admin.php like:

function company() {}
function usermanagement() {}

but I guess it wasn't that effective since it will include lots of functions later on as I try to migrate my native php codes into this MVC architecture framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your issue is that you like the way routes work but don't want people to be able to visit index.php/company/ and rather prefer that they visit admin/company you can always do:

```
class Company extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        if ( $this->uri->segment(1) != "admin" ) {
            redirect('admin/company/'.$this->uri->segment(3));
        }
    }

...
```

Although bear in mind that you would probably need a more complete URL forming method than just adding `$this->uri->segment(3)` but the general pattern is there.

Comment: Perfect. This is what I'm looking for. But, I have a question, why is it it throw an error on the redirect part?. If I remove this, it's all working fine. I also autoloaded the uri but that line still throws an error.

Comment: You need to load the URL helper to use redirect() http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Comment: Oh, they are loaded. What I mean is, if I add this code on the redirect, it will throw an error: $this-uri->segment(3)

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on my part. It should be `$this->uri->segment(3)`, edited to reflect.

Comment: i didn't notice that typo. lol.. by the way, thanks for helping. it helps a lot. Do you know any articles to boost my knowledge on codeigniter with an exception to their documentation?

Answer (score 0):

You can add more functions in your 'admin' controller, so, default page is:

```
 public function index() {
              $this->load->view('view_admin');
           }
```

'Subpage' is:

```
 public function company() {
              $this->load->view('view_company');
           }
```

etc, etc...

Comment: I've tried it. But it isn't effective as I need to write more codes later on my project and tends to confuse me later on. I'm new to MVC architecture and my previous sites are from native php.